# "Expected Expression" Accessing Selector When Creating Radio Buttons

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create radio buttons programmatically based on data in Firebase. The Firebase data will essentially be a number, and then I plan on using that number in a for loop to populate the necessary number of radio buttons. I have previous experience in Android and am trying to translate to swift:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class PollController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var passLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pollImage: UIImageView!
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
var pollRef: FIRDatabaseReference!

var pass = ""
var passedImageURL = ""

var posX = 0;
var posY = 0;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    pollRef = ref.child("Polls").child(pass)
    passLabel.text = pass
    pollImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: passedImageURL), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "test"))

    pollRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
    let numberOfChildren = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "answers").childrenCount
    self.passLabel.text = String(numberOfChildren)
    print(numberOfChildren)

    var buttons = [UIButton]()
        // create button1
    for x in 0..<numberOfChildren {
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.posX, y: self.posY, width: 60, height: 20))
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
            button.setTitle("No", for: .normal)
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox untick.png")!, for: .normal)
            // if the selected button cannot be reclick again, you can use .Disabled state
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkboxredtick.png")!, for: .selected)
            button.tag = Int(x)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction(_:))), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            myStackview.addSubview(button)
            buttons.append(button)
            // create other buttons and add into buttons ...
        }

    func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton!){
            for button in buttons {
                button.isSelected = false
            }
            sender.isSelected = true
            // you may need to know which button to trigger some action
            // let buttonIndex = buttons.indexOf(sender)
        }
    })


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

  }
```

EDIT: I was able to narrow down the issue, however I am still having some issues understanding selectors and senders. It seems that's where my error is coming in, as there is a red exclamation stating "Expected Expression" on the line of my #selector.

[image]

Comment: It would help if you spend some time to learn the language instead of translating it statement by statement. If you want a quick way (not ideal) refer to the syntax of statements / lines with a with red exclamation mark

Comment: Thanks, I did go 1 by 1 on the red marks but wanted to hopefully get some guidance first. I understand the syntax is different but any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you spend some time to learn the language instead of translating it statement by statement. If you want a quick way (not ideal) refer to the syntax of statements / lines with a with red exclamation mark

## For statement

```
for (x in 0 ..< numberOfChildren) { }
```

Swift uses type inference, it determines the type based on the value assigned.

## Selector

It needs to be the name of the function with function argument labels on it

## myStackView

Refer `UIStackView`

```
addArrangedSubview
```

## buttons

Learn Swift `Optionals`